# Custom off-topic reasons on the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, close-reasons

When another user votes to close a question using a custom reason, the Android app is useless for supporting that vote. It lists two "other" options:

[image: IMG:]

Both led to the empty text box asking for a reason.

Probably the bottom one should be using the actual custom reason.

Answer (score 2):

[This was fixed in January.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295336/custom-close-votes-broken-in-ios-app/314201)

Comment: Excellent. I think I had seen that and asked AndrewT (who helps out triaging Android bugs) if he could verify it, but neither of us had a testable instance on hand.